# What is the better way to pause a lengthy operation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am processing unknown number of items in a loop. Processing each item takes variable time. As the overall operation is lengthy and to give the end user more control, I want to provide a pause button.
The items to process are provided by a third party generator function and I can't modify it. So total number of items is unknown.

Following is my attempt to implement the feature:

```js
let processed = 0;
let paused = false;
let resume = () => {};

// a third party function, which I can't modify
async function* getItems() {
  for (;;) yield 1;
}

// placeholder for a lengthy operation
async function process(item) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

// is this a better way to implement pause?
async function enforcePause() {
  if (paused)
    return new Promise(resolve => {resume = resolve});
  else return Promise.resolve();
}

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if (paused) {
    resume();
    paused = false;
    btn.textContent = 'Pause';
  } else {
    paused = true;
    btn.textContent = 'Resume';
  }
});

// a lengthy operation 
async function processAll() {
  for await (let item of getItems()) {
    await process(item);
    counter.textContent = ++processed;
    
    await enforcePause();
  }
}

processAll();
```

```html
<p>Progress: <span id="counter">0</span></p>
<button id="btn">Pause</button>
```

My queries are:

1. Is there a better way to implement this? Should I be looking for a library?
2. If no, what improvements can be made to above code? any caveats?
3. If the total number of items were finite and the items were stored in a collection, is there a better solution possible?

Comment: Is `process` actually asynchronous? If not, you'd need to change this a bit; otherwise this is a perfectly fine approach.

Comment: "*any caveats?*" - at first I thought there's a race condition between the click handler and `enforcePause`, but there isn't - only the slight disconnect that `process` is not immediately cancelled, but continues to run, when pressing the "Pause" button. Changing this would require that `process` must be cancellable, or would mean deceiving the user.

Comment: Is `getItems` really an *asynchronous* iterator? If not, you're fine, but if it is, and there's a chance that it's slower than your `process()` function, you might want to throw in another `await enforcePause();` at the *start* of the loop body, before calling `process(item)`.

Comment: @Bergi thanks! 1) To cancel the `process` I will have to simply discard the result and reuse the item on resume. 2) Yes, `getItems` is asynchronous. Putting one more `await enforcePause()` before `process` makes sense. That will result in caching the item till user resumes, but this is not an issue.